# Simple regular expression question

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression for one of my particular requirement explained below.  I believe that this may be very simple & basic for the regex experts.

A regular expression that matches one or more words in a line.  Consider this line:

```
QRYNUMB0007 = SELECT EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, CITY, STATE, COUNTRY FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEEID = ?
```

In this case, for example, I want to find out whether the words I'm searching/looking for *SELECT*, *FIRSTNAME* and *EMPLOYEE* are available in the same line.  Order of occurrence of the words in the line is not important in this case, but all the 3 words should be present in the same line.

Comment: @eumiro: As I had already stated in my question, order of occurrence of the words is not important in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select any one of them

```
/select|firstname|employee/i
```

If you want to actually find all of them

```
/select/i && /firstname/i && /employee/i
```

And, depending on your language, things can be simpler, eg Python

```
STRING=mystring.lower()
if "select" in STRING and "firstname" in STRING and "employee" in STRING:
    print "...."
```

Comment: Actually, am trying to use this regular expression from within Linux vi editor.  I've another question here, where EOL (end-of-line) is specified in this expression?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):</strike>

```
SELECT|FIRSTNAME|EMPLOYEE
```

Well, regexes don't really support the `AND` operator, as others have said. Since you're in `vim` you don't have access to that operator at the language level either.

You can try permutations:

```
/SELECT.*FIRSTNAME.*EMPLOYEE|SELECT.*EMPLOYEE.*FIRSTNAME/
```

Or alternatively, to avoid matching things like `EMPLOYEEFIRSTNAME`:

```
/SELECT.+FIRSTNAME.+EMPLOYEE|SELECT.+EMPLOYEE.+FIRSTNAME/
```

Comment: édéric: All the 3 words should be present and not any one of them.